# Print date with polish month names

Tags: pdftex, texworks

I'd like to print Current Date to PDF, using pdfLaTeX in TeXworks (Tex Live 2018). The problem, which occured to me is, that command `\date{\today}` prints me the current date, but with English names of Months. I'd like to see there Polish names. Like:

```
January -> Styczeń
February -> Luty
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this, by changing some config, without writing multiline code?

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage[polish]{babel}` to your document preamble do what you want?

Comment: Next time please post a full minimal example, so we know what you are doing. Then we'd know if you are  using `babel` or not as David suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all.
I'm sorry for not passing all of the information. It helped adding line

```
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
```

Thank you very much! Please recieve my appology. To by correct, I will post full (after modifications) example, which works for me. I've taken it from guide, which is located [here](http://www.docs.is.ed.ac.uk/skills/documents/3722/3722-2014.pdf).
Thanks again.
Bye. Mike.

Post Scriptum: I've only added mentioned line `\usepackage[polish]{babel}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{My First Document}
\author{My Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
This is the {\color{red}introduction.}

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Stage 1}
\label{sec1}
The first part of the methods.

\subsection{Stage 2}
The second part of the methods.

\section{Results}
Here are my results. Referring to section \ref{sec1} on page \pageref{sec1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want to load any packages (you want a minimal change....) Also, you did not provide a minimal example, but the article class file contains

```
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
```

Because it is a TeX `\def`, it can be overwritten with another `\def` without the usual LaTeX existence crosschecks.

Here is an example assuming that you can typeset the UTF-8 characters. Otherwise, you'd have to replace them with LaTeX escaped characters.

```
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  Styczeń\or Luty\or Marzec\or Kwiecień\or Maj\or Czerwiec\or
  Lipiec\or Sierpień\or Wrzesień\or Październik\or Listopad\or Grudzień\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
```

Comment: Since recently, UTF-8 is the default input encoding for `pdflatex` too (https://www.latex-project.org/news/2018/04/10/issue28-of-latex2e-news-released/).

Comment: @gusbrs Ok, nice, but that is just the file encoding. It does not solve the issue that many characters cannot be mapped to a font. But I am not sure.

Comment: You still need the font encoding I suppose, and the font has to support the characters. But, as far as I understand it, with UTF-8 as input encoding, there is no need to use escaped characters any longer (which was already the case if you used `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`).